# App initially running slowly?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, subview

In an app that I am currently developing, It runs very slowly for the first few seconds. I am almost 100% sure this is because it tiles a large background onto the view. I have tried to load the view before putting it on the screen by checking whether all of the subviews existed. However, this value is always 168(the number of subviews there should be after loading) which means the subviews are being added but they are not being fully loaded in some way. Does somebody know why this is?

Comment: Could you try it using delegates? Load it in the background and then make it visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial how to do actions in background [Ray Wenderlich:Multithreading and Grand Central Dispatch on iOS for Beginners Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

As Paul Peelen suggested; do it in the background.
Grand Central Dispatch is an excellent resource for tiling images.